# PCA time trajectory plots

Tags: r, time-series, pca, multivariate-analysis

I am studyng the effect of chemotherapy/surgery on the patients' metabolomics profiles and I have 4 time points. I would like to see if patients who achieved good outcome have a trajectory over the time that differs from not responders patients.

I found an article where it is reported a similar situation and they carried out a PCA using the average PCA scores, but I do not have idea how to performed this analysis.
Many thanks for the help.[image]

Comment: Could you please give a citation for the article (full citation, not just a link)?

Comment: Dai, D., Gao, Y., Chen, J. et al. Time-resolved metabolomics analysis of individual differences during the early stage of lipopolysaccharide-treated rats. Sci Rep 6, 34136 (2016). https://doi.org/10.1038/srep34136